# What Does the 'Forgeborn Fireheart' Skill Do?

Tags: conclave

The description for the *Forgeborn Fireheart* ability is as follows:

> The subject regains a use of an ability. Forgeborn Fireheart can only be used when at least moderately wounded.

I thought this might have meant that I'd get two 'major action' uses, but I didn't.

What does it do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some abilities can only be used a certain number of times per encounter. I believe Forgeborn Fireheart allows you to restore the use of one of these abilities.

Comment: I could find out if @GnomeSlice would vote...